# Any way in C to forward declare struct in header without having to use pointer in other files?

Tags: c, struct, header-files, forward-declaration

Suppose I have this in list.h:

```
typedef struct list_t list_t;
typedef struct list_iter_t list_iter_t;
list_iter_t iterator(list_t *list);
```

and then define them in list.c:

```
typedef struct node_t {
    ...
} node_t;

struct list_iter_t {
    node_t *current;
    // this contains info on whether the iterator has reached the end, etc.
    char danger;
};

struct list_t {
    ...
}

list_iter_t iterator(list_t *list) {
    list_iter_t iter;
    ...
    return iter;
}
```

Is there anything I can do aside from including the struct declaration in the header file so that in some file test.c I can have:

```
#include "list.h"

void foo(list_t *list) {
    list_iter_t = iterator(list);
    ...
}
```

Like maybe tell the compiler the storage size of list_iter_t somehow? It's inconvenient to have to use a pointer (not because it's a pointer, but for other reasons), but at the same time I would like to hide the implementation details as much as possible.

Comment: Are you asking if you can declare variable whose type is incomplete? You can't.

Comment: No there isn't. You can't declare an incomplete type. Also, your typedefs are wrong. They should be `typedef struct list_t list_t;
typedef struct list_iter_t list_iter_t;`. Think about it this way, if what you ask for were possible, there would be no such thing as an opaque type in C. Someone tries to hide the innards of a struct from you by giving you only a header containing a forward declaration and a library that goes along with it, you could simply declare an instance in your code and use it.

Comment: Okay thanks. (The absence of "struct" in the typedef was a typo.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The succinct answer is "No".

The way you tell the compiler the size of a `struct` is by telling it the details of how the `struct` is structured.   If you want to allocate an object, rather than a pointer to the object, the compiler must know the complete type of the object.  You also can't access the members of a structure via a pointer to the structure if the type is incomplete.  That is, the compiler must know the offset and type of the member to generate the correct code to access `someptr->member` (as well as to allocate `somevalue` or access `somevalue.member`).

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to tell the compiler the size of the structure, using a dummy definition like:

```
struct node_t {
    char dummy[sizeof(struct { ... })];
};
```

(with the proper definition instead available to the implementation file).

Formally this causes undefined behaviour; it is likely to somewhat work in practice, though.

You are probably best off just including the proper structure definition though, and leaving a comment to the effect that code should simply not touch the internal members.

Comment: How about having the "real" file use a `union` of the fake type and a real structure?

Comment: To clarify: if a header file has `union {unsigned long data[50];} FOO;` and the .C file has `union {unsigned long data[50]; REAL_STRUCTURE dat;} FOO;`, would behavior be defined provided that the size and alignment requirements of `dat` were no bigger than those of `data`?

Comment: @supercat: No, that would be just as undefined - for two unions declared in different translation units to be compatible types there has to be a one-to-one correspondence between members.

Comment: If the union includes both a type which forces alignment, and an `unsigned char[]`, would a pointer to one union's `unsigned char[]` be valid as a pointer to the other union [I think it would have to be valid as a pointer to the other union's `unsigned char[]`, and I think a pointer to that union's unsigned char[] would be valid as a pointer to that union].

Comment: @supercat: No, you can't just cast any pointer to `unsigned char` to a pointer to a union even if that union contains an `unsigned char` member.  If you're not convinced maybe you should ask this as a new question so it can get some more eyes.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue. Using the `char[]` would guarantee that one could safely memcpy() one to the other, but not overlay via pointers. An implementation could theoretically have e.g. a fast area of RAM which was accessible to the CPU but not the FPU, and could put in such an area any `struct` or `union` of static or automatic duration which didn't contain any floating-point numbers (`malloc` couldn't use that area, though).  Given a pointer to either space returned by `malloc` or a union which "legitimately" contains a float, one could access floating-point numbers within it.

Comment: There's no guarantee, however, that one would legitimately be able to access a `float` stored within a union whose space was statically or automatically allocated as a type which didn't contain any floating-point types. While I don't know of any machines or compilers which together implement the particular restrictions I described, I think such a thing would be legal under the standard.  Am I understanding right?  (I like to think of UB in terms of things an implementation would be allowed to do that would yield undesired results).