# Resolving circular dependencies using forward-declarations

Tags: c, circular-dependency

For the sake of this question, please disregard the software-design problems related to mutual dependencies, and focus on the technical aspect.

Please consider two header files, `a.h` and `b.h`. File `a.h` defines some struct which `b.h` requires. However,  `b.h` also defines a struct which `a.h` requires.

As I understand it, a usual technique to resolve this circular `#include` dependency, is in `b.h` instead of including `a.h`, it would forward-declare the struct definition it requires from `a.h`. This would look something like this:

**a.h**

```
// No nice typedef
struct MyThing_t {
    // ...
};
```

**B.h**

```
// Other things omitted 

typedef struct MyThing_t MyThing;
// ... proceed using MyThing
```

As I understand it, this is supposed to compiler and work.

But - why does it work? How is the compiler aware of the name `MyThing_t` when it's compiling `b.h`? What is the mechanism here?

Also - why shouldn't I include the `typedef` also in `a.h`, for use by using modules which `a.h` doesn't have a circular dependency with?

Comment: You are probably missing one important part in your question, that you end up using pointers only unless the struct has been defined fully i.e. the storage size is known. Size of a pointer is known regardless. Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7278936/5781248 might be useful.

Comment: It's the *linker* that resolves symbols after compilation. Also, in `b.h`, only a *pointer* to a `MyThing` is permitted.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I see. Should `b.h` be able to access MyThing's members, such as m->num?

Comment: @AvivCohn: Nope. Remember, a struct definition is simply a description of a memory layout. Without the full definition, `b.h` has no idea of the size or layout of a `MyThing`, only that it exists *somewhere*. The linker will resolve that.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield If so, than essentially isn't the above technique pointless? Not much to do with a pointer you can't dereference. Are there alternatives?

Comment: A pointer can be passed to a function that is in the same compile unit as the definition of struct. https://alastairs-place.net/blog/2013/06/03/encapsulation-in-c/

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to deal with this situation is to define the struct in a different header, like `basic.h`, or some such, and have `a.h` and `b.h` both include that header. Because in `b.h` this

`typedef struct MyThing_t MyThing`

forward declaration declares an *opaque* type that allows you to only use a `MyThing*` pointer. Because `b.h` has no idea of what the size or memory layout of the struct actually is. This is actually a very common C idiom, as it allows encapsulation of the internals of a struct, and allows declaration in the header file of functions that operate on that pointer without needing to know the implementation.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. I'll try extracting to a common header. Anyway, in the above example, is there a reason to not declare the `typedef` in `a.h` too? For use by additional modules which depend on `a.h`.

Comment: @AvivCohn: In the posted example, the only reason to define the struct with a typedef (along with the full definition) would be to save having to type "struct MyThing_t" every time and just type "MyThing".

Answer (score 0):

It's `typedef *struct* MyThing_t MyThing;`; no declaration is needed for `struct Mything_t` (which can cause bugs, so typedefs-for-everything is a good idea).

I find it's better to write a single `fwd.h` file (or for large projects, per directory) with all the typedefs in it, and include that at the beginning of all other headers.

Incidentally, you should avoid names ending with `_t` unless you work for POSIX.

Comment: How is it possible for `b.h` to even mention `MyThing_t` when it hasn't included `a.h`? Shouldn't the compiler, which is only aware of one file at a time, complain?

Comment: The code you posted can't compile. Either you have a typo, or it's incomplete. Note that if you're compiling as C++ (common in MS land or with shared headers) there is an implicit typedef for the tag name.

Comment: I fixed the question following your correction. So the question remains, how does `b.h` compile while mentioning `MyThing_t`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, this is supposed to compiler and work.

Yes and no.  Each header can be `#include`d in a source file independently of the other, but `B.h` does not provide a definition of `struct MyThing_t`. Where no definition is in scope, that's an incomplete type, which greatly limits what you can do with it.

> But - why does it work? How is the compiler aware of the name
>   MyThing_t when it's compiling b.h?

If it is not already aware of `struct MyThing_t` before it reaches the `typedef`, the `typedef` *makes* it aware.

> What is the mechanism here?

A structure type with a tag can be used without a prior declaration or definition of that type, but only in the ways that an incomplete type may be used.  This is what allows structures to contain pointers to objects of their own type.  It can be used more generally to declare pointers to the type in question, and it can also be used in `typedef`s.  On the other hand, incomplete types may not be used in any way that requires knowledge of their storage size or (for structure and union types) their members' names or types.

> Also - why shouldn't I include the typedef also in a.h, for use by
>   using modules which a.h doesn't have a circular dependency with?

I don't know, why shouldn't you?  That would be more typical than splitting them up.  You do need to be careful about declaring the same `typedef` twice, though.  It's legal to do so in the latest versions of C, but it was not allowed in C90 and C99.